# Is operator lookup different for temporary/anonymous objects?

Tags: c++, inheritance, anonymous-objects

I am trying to understand why named and temporary (anonymous?) objects seem to behave differently when looking up an operator defined in a base class. In the following code I've made a wrapper around a variable of 'mytype' which I want to switch between double and std::complex through a compiler definition. To this wrapper I want to add an operator using a base type (similar to boost::operators). My interest is in the difference between the two (admittedly quite forced) cout lines in 'main'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

#include <complex>

#ifdef COMPLEX
typedef std::complex<double> mytype;
#else
typedef double mytype;
#endif

template <typename DerivedType, typename integertype>
struct Base
{    
    friend DerivedType& operator +=(DerivedType& lhs, const integertype& rhs)
    {
        std::cout << "base += version" << std::endl;
        return lhs += mytype(rhs);
    }
};

struct Wrapper : public Base<Wrapper, unsigned>
{
    Wrapper(const mytype& rhs) : m_value(rhs) {}

    Wrapper(const unsigned& rhs) : Wrapper(mytype(rhs)) {}

    Wrapper& operator += (const Wrapper& rhs)
    {
        std::cout << "wrapper version" << std::endl;
        m_value += rhs.m_value;
        return *this;
    }

    Wrapper& operator += (const mytype& rhs)
    {
        std::cout << "wrapper mytype version" << std::endl;
        m_value += rhs;
        return *this;
    }
     
    mytype m_value;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << (Wrapper(2.0) += 3u).m_value << std::endl;

    Wrapper t_MyWrapper(2.0);
    std::cout << (t_MyWrapper += 3u).m_value << std::endl;
}
```

if I compile without -DCOMPLEX I get the following output:

```
wrapper mytype version
5
base += version
wrapper mytype version
5
```

As far as I can tell, the first output in main ignores the operator+=(Wrapper&, const unsigned&) from the Base. It instead promotes the unsigned to a double (which is preferential to converting to a Wrapper) and calls the operator+=(Wrapper& const double&). The 'named object' however, does call the operator from the base type. Compiling with -DCOMPLEX leads to a compile error:

```
SimplifiedProblem.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
SimplifiedProblem.cxx:47:32: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator+=’ (operand types are ‘Wrapper’ and ‘unsigned int’)
   47 |     std::cout << (Wrapper(2.0) += 3u).m_value << std::endl;
      |                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
SimplifiedProblem.cxx:28:14: note: candidate: ‘Wrapper& Wrapper::operator+=(const Wrapper&)’
   28 |     Wrapper& operator += (const Wrapper& rhs)
      |              ^~~~~~~~
SimplifiedProblem.cxx:35:14: note: candidate: ‘Wrapper& Wrapper::operator+=(const mytype&)’
   35 |     Wrapper& operator += (const mytype& rhs)
      |              ^~~~~~~~
```

Considering that converting the unsigned to std::complex is not 'better' than to a 'Wrapper' (neither is a scalar type), the compile error makes sense, but I would like to understand why the operator from the base type is not used.

Moving the operator+=(Wrapper&, const unsigned&) to the wrapper directly avoids this problem, and removing the constructor Wrapper(const unsigned&) resolves the ambiguity when -DCOMPLEX. But I would like to understand if the rules for temporary object lookup are different or if something else is causing this behaviour.

Comment: Remove the overload that the compiler chose and it will tell you whether the remaining ones are viable in the first place. It will tell you what the issue is, namly that you can't bind a rvalue to a non-`const` lvalue reference.

Comment: A temporary can't bind to `DerivedType& lhs` so the friend operator declared in base is not a candidate.  The compiler then tries standard conversions and `3u` can be promoted to double.

Comment: It is no different than trying `void f(int&) {}; int main() { f(1); }`.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, indeed I didn't consider this. So there's no way to add the equivalent of operator+=(const unsigned&) in Wrapper through a base class? I don't strictly need it anyway, but now at least I understand what's going on.

Comment: @Tom_DB The equivalent in the base class via a `friend` would be two overloads, one taking a `const` reference and one taking a non-`const` reference. This will not resolve the ambiguity issue however.

Comment: Kate Gregory had an excellent presentation at one of the C++ conferences where she talked about "all the defaults are wrong" in C++.  One subtopic she mentioned was that constructors should be `explicit` by default implicitly, and need to **opt-out** of being `explicit`... *explicitly*.  Alas, that ship has sailed.  Maybe **C++ syntax 2** (or something inspired by Sutter's experiment) can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The `3u` literal converts implicitly into a `Wrapper` and thus both overloads of `operator+=` are possible candidates in the line the compiler flags to you.

One simple solution is to mark both `Wrapper` constructors with [`explicit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit). Then, they will never allow implicit conversion to a `Wrapper` but will always require you to type out the conversion as you did in the first line of `main`.